# Angular optimize api

Tags: angular, api

I trying to make a "BBoard" with angular.

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  {{ category.name }}
  <div><a pageScroll href="home#add">Nouveau sujet</a></div>
  <div *ngIf="hasTopics(category.id)">
    has topic
    <div *ngFor="let topic of getTopicsOf(category.id)">
      {{ topic.title }} 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my function:

```
getTopicsOf(id: number) {
  const topics = [];
  this.topics.forEach(element => {
    if (element[0].category_id === id) {
      topics.push(element[0]);
    }
  });
  console.log(topics);
  return topics;
}
```

The problem is this does infite loop and it's not recommanded, so I must use variable that already contain the category + topics. But I don't know how to do.

I get the topics and the categories separate:

```
getAll() {
  this.topicsService.getAll().subscribe((res) => {
    this.count = res.count;
    if (res.count > 0) {
      this.topics.push(res.topics);
    }
  });
}

getCategories() {
  this.topicsService.getAllCategories().subscribe((res) => {
    if (res.count > 0) {
      res.categories.forEach((cat) => {
        this.categories.push(cat);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Must I get all in one request ?

When I use HTML + PHP I can run REQUEST inside loop but with angular the logic change and this is not optimized at all. How would you do ? (The API is made with PHP vanilla)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to run two requests simultaneously. This way you'll have the response of two requests at the same time and can do anything with them.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

getAll() {
  forkJoin(this.topicsService.getAll(), this.topicsService.getAllCategories()).subscribe(data => {
    const { topicsRes, categoriesRes } = data;
    if (res.count > 0)
      this.count = topicsRes.count;

    if (categoriesRes.count > 0)
      this.categories = categoriesRes.categories;

    this.topics = [];
    topicsRes.topics.forEach(element => {
      if (element[0].category_id === id) {
        this.topics.push(element[0]);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.topics);
  });
}
```

Also I recommend using `filter` instead of that `forEach` for `topics`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585353/javascript-filter-method-confusion) for more info