# React Function filter does not work (no errors in the console)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my list, when I click on row, the background of the  changes color and the id of my row is added to the array of my state. It works, but when I do the reverse my array doesn't get empty when I use the filter function (line 15).

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Liste.css';
import Button from '../Button/Button';

function Liste(props) {

    const [nbLine, setNbLine] = useState([]);

    const clickLine = (e) =>
    {
        if (e.target.parentNode.className.length > 0)
        {
            console.log(e.target.parentNode.id);
            e.target.parentNode.classList.remove("lineClicked");
            nbLine.filter(line => line != e.target.parentNode.id);
            console.log(nbLine);         
        }
        else
        {
            e.target.parentNode.classList.add("lineClicked");
            nbLine.push(e.target.parentNode.id);
            console.log(nbLine);
        } 
    }

    const doubleClickLine = () =>
    {
        console.log("doubleClickLine"); 
    }

    return (
        <>
            <table className='tableList'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {props.headers.map((header, h) =>
                            <th key={h}>{header}</th>                   
                        )}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.records.map((record, r) =>
                        <tr key={r} id={props.table+"_"+record[0]} onClick={clickLine} onDoubleClick={doubleClickLine}>
                            {props.columns.map((column, c) =>
                                <td key={c}>{record[column]}</td>      
                            )} 
                        </tr>                
                    )}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan={7}>
                            {props.buttons.map((button, b) =>
                                <Button key={b} id={button[0]} type={button[1]} value={button[2]} click={button[3]}/>              
                            )}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default Liste;
```

[Here is the screen when I click (the elements are in the table).
Note: the data is fictitious.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgCrH.png)

And here is the screen when I click again (the elements resent in the array).

[And here is the screen when I click again (the elements resent in the array).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5eM5.png)

Why is the filter function not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript filter() method confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585353/javascript-filter-method-confusion)

Comment: "The `filter()` method returns an array containing a subset of the elements of the array on which it is invoked." Also, you should be using `setNbLine` to update your state rather than expecting `Array` methods to update it for you (assuming they're mutating the existing array and not returning a new one)

Comment: No, that doesn't help me. If I can do without the filter function, how do I add and remove an element from a state array without overwriting the previous elements? That's what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unlocked myself.

By replacing the state array with an object.

`const [nbLines, setNbLines] = useState({});`

By using the delete operator instead of the filter method.

`delete nbLines[e.target.parentNode.id];`

And by assigning a value to a key instead of the push method.

`nbLines[e.target.parentNode.id] = e.target.parentNode.id;`